# Accesing data of a ComboBox from BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, combobox

i'm having a really weird problem. I'm trying to get data from a combobox within a dowork event of a backgroundworker.

```
if (this.sortBox.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Friends" && this.sortBox.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Spotify")
//sortBox = ComboBox
```

This if is the problem. It just doesn't go in there, even tho it is true. Checked it in normal void and it worked, so it's just in the dowork event. But how am i supposed to invoke this and i thought i only had to invoke when i would try to modify the object on the ui. Really weird and i would be glad if someone would be able to clear this up a little bit!

Answer (score 2):

Another version:

```
        string value = "";
        sortBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
            if (sortBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                value = sortBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            }
        }));
        Console.WriteLine("value = " + value);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to simply pass the required data (a simple string if your example is right) to your long-running task when you start the `BackgroundWorker` so it can run independently from the UI.

If you really want to access the UI from the worker thread you can do it like this:

```
string result = null;
Action accessUI = () => result = sortBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
if (InvokeRequired)
    Invoke(accessUI); // this will run from the worker thread
else
    accessUI(); // and this one from the UI thread (direct access)
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Dispatcher which I can't remember how to get access to in Windows Forms (it being legacy technology and I haven't touched it for almost 10 years). In WPF there is a static Application class which exposes, however to make your ViewModel's (or in Windows Forms case Presenter) unit testable you should expose that as an injectable interface.